# Program stop at a statement (backgound.Visible=true). Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

This is my program:

```
{  
   statement1;  
   ...
   background.Visbile = true;
   ...
   statementx;
}
```

When I run this program, it stops at background.Visible=true; statement. Anybody know why?
More information:
background is TableLayoutPanel object.
'stop' mean program freeze and don't run to next statement.

I can't debug this program, only write log. Application just not proceed to the next line.

Comment: I realise that English might not be your first language, but you really need to provide a LOT more information if we are to help you.

Comment: Please do not re-type code from source when you ask about it, always copy and paste. You can remove code you don't need, but if you retype, chances are you'll introduce mistakes, and then people will try to help you with those instead of your real problem.

Comment: Assuming it's not a typo in the original code, we need a stack trace or something else to go on here.

Comment: I am sure it has to do to with the previous statement and to the data bindings / controls on the form. you shall provide more info if you wanna get help, cuz I just created a sample app with a TableLayoutPanel on it, and I set it's Visible property to true and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the comes before the { } that you say "This is my program"?

Answer (score 1):

Your code might have a cross-thread access problem. You might be getting an exception thrown, but since you're not debugging, it might be swallowed by the code elsewhere, and not shown to you, making your application appear frozen.

If you're using Threads or BackgroundWorkers in your code, you should perform operations on the UI components by checking if [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx), and then calling [`Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx).